# Ubuntu 20.04 overheating laptop when lid closes

Tags: dual-boot, suspend, power-management, laptop, overheating

I'm having some troubles with my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop(HP Victus 15 FA0031DX). Whenever I close the lid, my laptop is still using power, and ends up heating up. I closed the lid after every time of working and it got emergency shutdown after over heating.

Actually I've dual booted the ubuntu with windows 11, but it is working fine with windows as there is no such issue while using windows. It just heated up during suspend and sleep also in ubuntu.

Comment: How do you know that "it got emergency shutdown after over heating"?

Comment: It got over heating and got shutdown after some time. When I boot up again it shows me the message by BIOS that it got emergency shutdown after overheating.

Comment: Same here, I have a HP Victus 16 - (R0047NT). I didn't get any overheating messages but it's burning when I take it out from my bag. It's really weird.